# Jenkins randomly crashes

Tags: jenkins

my jenkins-server is randomly crashing, so I made sure to have the latest version and checked the logs, but they don't provide me with useful information. My question is: How to debug these crashes? Is there a way of increasing the loglevel?

Here is my log-output:

```
Running

 from: /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:33 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Jenkins home directory: /var/lib/jenkins found at: EnvVars.masterEnvVars.get("JENKINS_HOME")
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:35 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: HTTP Listener started: port=8080
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:35 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 running: controlPort=disabled
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:36 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:36 PM hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy createPluginWrapper
INFO: Plugin cvs.jpi is disabled
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:36 PM hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy createPluginWrapper
INFO: Plugin translation.jpi is disabled
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:36 PM hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy createPluginWrapper
INFO: Plugin subversion.jpi is disabled
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:36 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:36 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:36 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:41 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:41 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:41 PM org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils$BouncyCastleRegistration run
INFO: Trying to register BouncyCastle as a JCE provider
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:41 PM org.apache.sshd.common.util.SecurityUtils$BouncyCastleRegistration run
INFO: Registration succeeded
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:42 PM org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD start
INFO: Started SSHD at port 52235
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:42 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Completed initialization
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:43 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@271a2576: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Mon Nov 05 12:42:43 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:43 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@271a2576]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@28ce41cc
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:43 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@28ce41cc: defining beans [authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:44 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@654481bb: display name [Root WebApplicationContext]; startup date [Mon Nov 05 12:42:44 CET 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:44 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.web.context.support.StaticWebApplicationContext@654481bb]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@20e1ed5b
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@20e1ed5b: defining beans [filter,legacy]; root of factory hierarchy
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:44 PM hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener <init>
INFO: JNLP slave agent listener started on TCP port 52602
Nov 5, 2012 12:42:44 PM hudson.WebAppMain$2 run
INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running
```

Any hint for me?

Comment: The portion of log you've put up only shows it starting up. Is there anything more after that, before Jenkins crashes?

Comment: Also, what OS are you running on? Are you using the internal Winsone server or Tomcat? Is it running as a service?

Comment: Try running from command line (`java -jar jenkins.war`), and adding that output to question. How do you even know it crashes?

Comment: I'm running an ubuntu-server using nginx as a proxy. It obviously crashes because the ngnix sends me a "Bad Gateway" and (running 'top') I can visually see the process disappear in that moment. What benefit would bring me running the jar-File directly instead of using the init.d-script?

Comment: .. in case someone comes here from google
http://serverfault.com/questions/355516/jenkins-jvm-crashes-after-few-minutes-after-start

Answer (score 0):

To increase the log level of Jenkins itself, use the following parameter when starting Jenkins via the command line:

```
-Djava.util.logging.loglevel=FINE
```

This should alter the logging **as displayed in the Jenkins GUI**.